# MariaDB enabling page compression

Tags: mariadb

i recently moved from mysql to maria db , i want to enable page compression feature offered by mariadb , but i have no success with enabling it.

> https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/compression/

what i did

i installed lz4 algo as mentioned in above doc

i also run few commands which were OK.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
```

but when i run

```
set global innodb_compression_algorithm=lz4;
```

i get error

> Unknown system variable 'innodb_compression_algorithm'

so any idea how to fix it , basically i have 100mb database and i want to compress it

Comment: And `ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`?  Try another compression algo.

Comment: Then file a bug with mariadb.com .

Comment: @RickJames  ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED   it will use LZ77 compression algo which is legacy and not good , lz4 as fast and use less memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the MariaDB version that your are trying? Page compression was introduced in MariaDB 10.1. [more info here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/compression/)

Comment: i know that , i have latest version , i recently switched to mariadb

Comment: Answered on the MariaDB website, user was running MariaDB 10.0

Answer (score 2):

The main point here is that not all available compression formats are compiled in by default. As you can read here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/compression/

> Because all of these compression methods are not available by default
>   on all distributions and MariaDB server does not bundle them, you may
>   need to download the desired compression method package from the above
>   links, install the package and finally recompile MariaDB server from
>   the source distribution with:

So to use lz4 you will need to recompile mariadb from source.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting in my.cnf file

```
[mysqld]
innodb_compression_algorithm = lz4
```